# ¿Como sumar propiedades objeto en JS?

Tags: javascript

```js
    [
   {
      "order_number":"9427",
      "brand_name":"Romance",
      "product_name":"Test Brightness",
      "price":"54900",
      "quantity":"1",
      "total_discount":"0",
      "seller_commission_percent":"0.15",
      "logistic_cost":"3500",
      "seller_id":"1"
   },
   {
      "order_number":"9426",
      "brand_name":"Daytona",
      "product_name":"Test Finesse",
      "price":"32000",
      "quantity":"1",
      "total_discount":"0",
      "seller_commission_percent":"0.2",
      "logistic_cost":"3500",
      "seller_id":"2"
   },
   {
      "order_number":"9425",
      "brand_name":"Romance",
      "product_name":"Test Rover",
      "price":"47900",
      "quantity":"1",
      "total_discount":"0",
      "seller_commission_percent":"0.15",
      "logistic_cost":"3500",
      "seller_id":"1"
   },
]
```

Mi pregunta es la siguiente si tengo este objeto como puedo recorrer el objeto y sumar `price + seller_commission_percent`  en js, tomando en cuenta que debe sumarse por empresa (`brand_name`)

Si me pudieran ayudar gracias!...

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el código que has intentado.

Comment: Aclara un poco más sobre cómo debería quedar el json final, por ejemplo: poniendo un ejemplo del valor esperado.

Answer (score 4):

Haciendo `.reduce` puedes ir agrupando las marcas y en el medio le vas sumando los montos:

```js
const obj = [{"order_number":"9427","brand_name":"Romance","product_name":"Test Brightness","price":"54900","quantity":"1","total_discount":"0","seller_commission_percent":"0.15","logistic_cost":"3500","seller_id":"1"},{"order_number":"9426","brand_name":"Daytona","product_name":"Test Finesse","price":"32000","quantity":"1","total_discount":"0","seller_commission_percent":"0.2","logistic_cost":"3500","seller_id":"2"},{"order_number":"9425","brand_name":"Romance","product_name":"Test Rover","price":"47900","quantity":"1","total_discount":"0","seller_commission_percent":"0.15","logistic_cost":"3500","seller_id":"1"}]


const res = obj.reduce((p, c) => {
    p[c.brand_name] = (p[c.brand_name] || 0)+(c.price * c.quantity) + 1 + c.seller_commission_percent * 1   
    return p;
}, {});


console.log(res);
```

Estoy asumiendo que la comisión se agrega al total, por eso hago 1+comisión. De cualquier manera la cuenta no es tan importante, es solo sumar restar y multiplicar, lo importante es el agrupamiento.

Comment: Gracias bro es lo que necesitaba

Answer (score 0):

Con la función `.map()` podes recorrer y reescribir el objeto o agregarle un nuevo valor.

```js
var json = [
   {
      "order_number":"9427",
      "brand_name":"Romance",
      "product_name":"Test Brightness",
      "price":"54900",
      "quantity":"1",
      "total_discount":"0",
      "seller_commission_percent":"0.15",
      "logistic_cost":"3500",
      "seller_id":"1"
   },
   {
      "order_number":"9426",
      "brand_name":"Daytona",
      "product_name":"Test Finesse",
      "price":"32000",
      "quantity":"1",
      "total_discount":"0",
      "seller_commission_percent":"0.2",
      "logistic_cost":"3500",
      "seller_id":"2"
   },
   {
      "order_number":"9425",
      "brand_name":"Romance",
      "product_name":"Test Rover",
      "price":"47900",
      "quantity":"1",
      "total_discount":"0",
      "seller_commission_percent":"0.15",
      "logistic_cost":"3500",
      "seller_id":"1"
   },
];

var newJson = json.map(function(v, k) {
  return Object.assign({}, v, { suma: parseFloat(v.price) + parseFloat(v.seller_commission_percent) });
});

console.log(newJson);
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta es mi propuesta para solucionarlo:

```js
var datos =    [
   {
      "order_number":"9427",
      "brand_name":"Romance",
      "product_name":"Test Brightness",
      "price":"54900",
      "quantity":"1",
      "total_discount":"0",
      "seller_commission_percent":"0.15",
      "logistic_cost":"3500",
      "seller_id":"1"
   },
   {
      "order_number":"9426",
      "brand_name":"Daytona",
      "product_name":"Test Finesse",
      "price":"32000",
      "quantity":"1",
      "total_discount":"0",
      "seller_commission_percent":"0.2",
      "logistic_cost":"3500",
      "seller_id":"2"
   },
   {
      "order_number":"9425",
      "brand_name":"Romance",
      "product_name":"Test Rover",
      "price":"47900",
      "quantity":"1",
      "total_discount":"0",
      "seller_commission_percent":"0.15",
      "logistic_cost":"3500",
      "seller_id":"1"
   }
]


var objetoSuma = {}


datos.forEach( x => {
  
  if( !objetoSuma.hasOwnProperty(x.brand_name) ){ 
    objetoSuma[x.brand_name] = 0
  } 
  
  var operacion = Number(x.price) *  ( 1 + Number (x.seller_commission_percent) )
  objetoSuma[x.brand_name] +=  operacion
  

})

console.log(objetoSuma)
```